# How to query the data that has been modified in last 30 MINUTES

Tags: soql, formula, query, sandbox, dynamic-soql

we have Order__c as custom object. we are trying to extract the past 30 minutes record.
`where LastModifiedDate=TODAY and HOUR_IN_DAY(LastModifiedDate) > 0.5`  is not working

We tried  SOQL :

```
 SELECT count() FROM Order__c  where LastModifiedDate=TODAY and HOUR_IN_DAY(LastModifiedDate) > 0.5
```

HOW DO I FETCH PAST 30 minute records only  using Where clause filter?

Comment: Is `Apex` an option?

Comment: No. Only we   have to write in pure SOQL . because data integration tool understand only SOQL  while migrating the record.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way might be to make the following `Minutes_Since_Modified__c` formula:

```
(NOW() - LastModifiedDate) * 24 * 60
```

Then to query for it:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Minutes_Since_Modified__c <= 30
```

---

If you can use `Apex`, then use a `Datetime` instance.

```
Datetime halfHourBack = Datetime.now().addMinutes(-30);
List<MyObject__c> records = [
    SELECT count() FROM MyObject__c
    WHERE LastModifiedDate >= :halfHourBack
];
```

If not, you can query the literal value as long as you can construct it using [ISO 8601](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004680&). For example at 12:30 PM it would look like:

```
List<MyObject__c> records = [
    SELECT count() FROM MyObject__c
    WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2016-08-09T12:00:00Z
];
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43703/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-vickps).