# Soql query to fetch the records based on time

Tags: soql

How to fetch the records which has been modified in last 30 minutes without using apex?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to make the following `Minutes_Since_Modified__c` formula:

```
(NOW() - LastModifiedDate) * 24 * 60
```

Then to query for it:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Minutes_Since_Modified__c <= 30
```

Please refer to this [Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136177/how-to-query-the-data-that-has-been-modified-in-last-30-minutes) for more info.

Comment: @StuartMittal Can you [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/162617/edit) your question to provide more details about what context you will be using this soql in? I can't think of any soql I've used that I didn't use in apex (developer console queries aside).

Comment: Please find my updated answer